# Django 1.8 show_change_link in inline not showing links

Tags: django-admin

I added show_change_link = True to an inline in Django 1.8, but the links are not added to the inlined items. Every model in the app is registered in the admin. Am I missing something? I can only find one sentence regarding this feature in the documentation.

EDIT:

```
class TheInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TheModel
    readonly_fields = ['timestamp']
    extra = 0
    show_change_link = True
```

I am not using any custom admin like grappelli, and all the models in the app are registered in the admin.

Comment: can you publish your admin.py? It's working ok for me. Are you using some customized admin like grappelli? Does the foreign key field that you want to edit have a registered admin module?

Answer (score 5):

I had this trouble without customized admin templates, but i realized that i didn't have the another model registered in the admin. So, don't forget to register the inline model to the admin.

Answer (score 3):

Got it! A while back I made a customized admin template for another view, and I didn't realize affected everything in the admin - just wasn't thinking. You got me going in the right direction OriolJ. Thanks!